# How to make python invoke a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I am rather new at this, so please cut me some slack.

I am working in a web application using google app engine. My server runs using Python, and when the user visits my "/" page, the server gets some HTML source code from a website and places it into a variable called `html_code`.

Now I would like to pass the `html_code` variable to the client so he can analyze it using JavaScript. Is this possible? How can I achieve this? Please provide examples if possible.

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Comment: This is unfair. I did research but it lead me nowhere. So why should I post it here? The rules say I must be specific to my problem and not waste time with anything else and that is what I do. Furthermore, not everyone has the same level of knowledge that you have, and I never claimed to be an expert in the matter. I shall report your post for bad conduit, discrediting and lack of will to even understand my problem, nevertheless to help me solve it.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix what request handling & templating languages are you using for your learning?

Comment: I am not using templates at all. I started with Python a few weeks ago, and that is the language I am using to handle client requests so far. Is there anything else I should keep in mind?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to send a piece of html to a browser that won't disrupt the existing layout and functioning of the page, but still take place in DOM (hence be accessible from JS). In that case you may consider a hidden/invisible iframe.

Comment: But the <iframe> tag will still appear. I guess I would have to remove it later by using jQuery right? I am not even sure if that would be possible at run time :S

Answer (score 1):

Note, the following is very very quick and dirty way of getting something to the client side.

Based upon https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction the following makes use of webapp2 and jinja2. "html_code" would be available for usage within a file named index.html. How you render / surface the fetched document is up to you, but as has been previously mentioned an iframe would probably work well in this situation.

```
import os
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import webapp2
import jinja2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html_code = urlfetch.fetch('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936253/how-to-make-python-invoke-a-javascript-function')
        template_values = {
            'html_code': html_code.content
        }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Never heard of Jinja before, thanks for the tip!